# Post ads in own web and mobile application

Tags: php, android, laravel, codeigniter

I'm creating my own website. In the admin side of it I would like to create a feature of posting my own advertisement without going to the actual site (ebay etc.). Is it possible  to integrate different advertisement sites to post ads in my own website or mobile application?

Comment: So you want ads without links? Not sure who wants to buy such an ad. But sure it's possible, but I assume you have to contact each ad buyer yourself

Comment: No, I want to to post ads on ebay using my own website.

Comment: ebay has an API for posting ads. Are you writing your own web-site or using a CMS? If you are writing the website yourself, look into developer.ebay.com. If you are using a CMS, look for a module or plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!